# in laravel gates always return false

Tags: laravel

gates `Gate::define('edit-setting',function($login){     return $login->isAdmin; });`

in Controller
`if(Gate::allows('edit-setting',Auth::guard('logindetail')->user())) {             echo "gate in" }`

this always return false
and if i change the allows to denies it work

Comment: can we see isAdmin?

Comment: public function isAdmin()
       {
              return $this->role;
       }

Comment: gates already get the authenticated user passed to them, you do not pass the user yourself when doing authorization checks

Comment: not worked even i removed the parameter

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `Auth::shouldUse('logindetail');` before calling Gate methods if you are using non-default guard.

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
Gate::define('edit-setting',function($login){
    return $login->isAdmin(); 
});
```

Controller.php

```
\Auth::shouldUse('logindetail');

if(Gate::allows('edit-setting')) {
     echo "gate in";
}
```

User.php

```
public function isAdmin() {
    return $this->role == 'admin' || $this->role == 'superadmin';
}
```

Comment: i have added that brackets but still im getting false

Comment: What is $this->role returned? Is a relation or attribute?

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that isAdmin function is getting called.

Comment: $this->role 
role is column in database

Comment: isAdmins function is properly  called when i try in controller

Comment: What is the value of role?

Comment: role is store all user role 
like
admin
superadmin
dto
current role value is admin

Comment: and the same method is getting called when making policy

Comment: Can you add dd on gate to see if the gate is called?
`Gate::define('edit-setting',function($login){
  dd('called');
  return $login->isAdmin; 
});`

Comment: when dd it return false

Comment: Seems the gate is not getting called. Where you define the gate?

Comment: in authserviceprovider

Comment: Updated the answer, please try

Comment: in App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Gate::define("edit",function($login){
            if($login->id==1)
            {
                dd('called');
                return true;
            }
            else
            false;
        });

Comment: Yes, I know. Please see my updated answer above the comments.

Comment: add `\Auth::shouldUse('logindetail');` before calling any Gate methods